# socket connection in iOS and background tasks

Tags: ios, sockets, background-process, nsstream

I am designing an app that needs to exchange data in real time over network and I am planning to use socket connection to achieve this. To keep the socket connection open in background I plan to declare my app as a VOIP app (I already know apple's rule prohibiting this and willing to take the risk), and use keepAliveTimeout to keep connections alive.
Now can I declare and own a socket which will listen to any incoming data or I have to use an existing/specific socket given by Apple? Also is the port unique per app or per phone? Means if my app is continuing in background and also a call comes over Skype would they interfere with each other?
Thanks in advance for response. Help would be appreciated.

Comment: Interfere in what sense?

Comment: What will happen if a my server sends data and Skype server sends data at the same time?

Comment: then the one chunk of data will arrive first, the other one second.

Comment: Does that mean there is only one socket available per iPhone and all VOIP apps use that listening socket only? Can you please cite apple developer document if possible?

Comment: IDK. In general, you shouldn't worry about that.